# Is there a way to fix file location/indexing issues on Windows 7 network shared drives?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

The problem I am having is that a file is downloaded onto X drive into a "Downloads" folder, and I think take that file and put it in a TV Shows folder, and the networked computer doesn't see it moved into the new folder. But, if I download a file on, say drive Z, and copy it to drive X to the TV Shows folder, the network drive sees it.

Comment: If the Folder on drive X is a Library instead of a Folder, you dont´s see the moving... These are some sort of links and they only point to the real file.